# How to calculate the amount of elapsed seconds between two ISO timestamps?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

With JS I am calculating the elapsed time as follows:

```
start = new Date().toISOString();
end = new Date().toISOString();
var time = last1 + ' - ' + last2;
```

For example, the above gives me to strings concatenated like this:

```
 '2020-04-09T13:15:52.838Z - 2020-04-09T13:16:09.704Z'
```

What is the correct way of getting the a delta value that represents the amount of time in seconds elapsed between `start` and `end`

Comment: Given Date objects, `date1 - date2` will give you the difference in milliseconds, divide by 1,000 to get seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment#diff`:

```js
const diff = (start, end) =>
  moment(end).diff(moment(start), 'seconds');
console.log( diff('2021-03-09T22:47:54.392Z', new Date().toISOString()) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend a Moment-based solution when the question was not asking about Moment.  Please see also https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/